# Ember.js: How to make children routes display in the parent resource

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

lately I have been reading through the ember documentation and following as best I can. I have made good progress which I thank God for but lately I have had troubles with routing. Specifically I can get templates to display in the application template but I cannot get children routes to display in the parent resources template. Instead the child template actually replaces it. Here's my code:

index.html

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modals">
        <h2>Modals Parent Route</h2>
       <p>This is the modals route which is common to all modals</p>
        {{outlet}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modals/layout">
       <h2>Layout Route</h2>
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modals/visuals">
       <h2>Visuals Route</h2>
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modals/finish">
       <h2>Finish Route</h2>
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modals/preview">
       <h2>Preview Route</h2>
    </script>
```

App.js

```js
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('modals', { path:'/modals' }, function(){
    this.route('layout');
    this.route('visuals');
    this.route('finish');
    this.route('preview');
    });
});
App.LayoutRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('modals.layout',{
           into: 'modals',
        });
    }
```

This is not the full code but I thought it would be all that pertains to this topic. Please feel free to ask me if you need the full file contents.

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com is way better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used ember-cli and finally figured out a way to get this working. I used the ember-cli g route to generate my routes. I ran it once for each of my routes except for application. After that things just worked properly. Here is a git repository that someone created for me that will help anyone with this same problem : https://github.com/mooror/mooror. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

the `renderTemplate` method you are using is completely overriding the template for `modals` that is why, get rid of it. Ember handles the rendering of templates for you, there's no need for it with the basic functionality you are trying to achive.

Comment: I tried removing all of my renderTemplate method and I get the same results. Perhaps this is what ember is supposed to do by default. Because my layout,visuals,finish,and preview routes are showing up just fine but its almost as if they are using the application handlebars templates {{outlet}} instead of the {{outlet}} inside my modals handlebars template. I tried adding a h2 and p tag with the outlet in the modals handlebars template: `<h2>Modals Parent Route</h2>
<p>This is the modals route which is common to all modals</p>
{{outlet}}` but the h2 and p contents don't show up.

Comment: @BenForg Are you naming everything correctly? you need to be visiting `/modals/layout` and the route for that should be called ModelsLayoutRoute

Answer (score 0):

If you want nested templates you need nested routes.

```
this.resource('parent', function() {
  this.route('child');
});
```

See: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This might help me work out a solution however it is not the complete answer I was looking for as I'm not sure how I get the child to display inside my parent resource (modals) template. When I go to the index#/modals/layout page the h2 tag does display properly. But instead of being underneath the h2 and p from my modals template it is all by itself.

Comment: Unfortunately If I'm reading the docs right it looks like this is the normal functionality.   "First, the posts template will be rendered into the {{outlet}} in the application template. Then, the posts/index template will be rendered into the {{outlet}} in the posts template.
If the user then navigates to /posts/favorites, Ember.js will **replace** the {{outlet}} in the posts template with the posts/favorites template."      [link](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/concepts/naming-conventions/#toc_the-index-route)